# Not able to get tokens / msal objects in angularJS after successful login for AzureAD

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am using msal.js 1.3.2 library for azure AD authentication in angularJS. After successful login after redirect, not getting userInfo object/msal objects as they are getting initialized after redirect. Here is my code

```
refApp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
}]);
refApp.config(['msalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$httpProvider', function (msalProvider,$httpProvider) {

    window.applicationConfig = {
        clientID: '<client id>'
    };

   msalProvider.init(
        {
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com',
            validateAuthority : false,
            clientID: applicationConfig.clientID,
            cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
            postLogoutRedirectUri: 'https://localhost:8080/logout',
            tokenReceivedCallback: function (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) { 
                console.log(token);
            }
        },
        $httpProvider
    );
}]);
refApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope','$stateParams', '$state', '$location','accountServices', 'msalAuthenticationService', function($scope,$rootScope,$stateParams, $state, $location, accountServices,msalService){
    $scope.dispWelcomePage = true;
    console.log(msalService); // prints all initialized values after redirect
    console.log(msal); // prints all initialized values after redirect
    if(!(typeof msalService.userInfo === 'undefined' )){
        console.log('userInfo.isAuthenticated is '+msalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated);}//Prints false
    $scope.redirectToLoginPage = function(){
    console.log("Redirecting to Login page");
    msalService.loginRedirect();
}
```

I have followed all the steps mentioned in below link
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angularjs
Please can some one suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are making acquire token request once you are successfully logged in

```
  // No callback. App resumes after closing or moving to new page.
                    // Check token and username
                    updateDataFromCache(_msal.loginScopes);
                    if (!_oauthData.isAuthenticated && _oauthData.userName && !_msal._renewActive) {
                        // id_token is expired or not present
                        var self = $injector.get('msalAuthenticationService');
                        self.acquireTokenSilent(_msal.loginScopes).then(function (token) {
                            if (token) {
                                _oauthData.isAuthenticated = true;
                            }
                        }, function (error) {
                            var errorParts = error.split('|');
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('msal:loginFailure', errorParts[0], errorParts[1]);
                        });
                    }
```

It would be better for you to avoid Angular js and upgrade to Angular with msal. As there will be more support and updates available.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. What I have observed is below set of code has never executed after successful login redirection. May be I am missing something    
$scope.$on("msal:loginSuccess", function () {
   console.log("loginSuccess");
  });


  $scope.$on("msal:loginFailure", function () {
   console.log("loginFailure");
  });


  $scope.$on("msal:notAuthorized", function (event, rejection, forResource) {
   console.log("notAuthorized");
  });


  $scope.$on("msal:acquireTokenSuccess", function (event, tokenOut) {
   console.log("acquireTokenSuccess");
  });

Comment: Also I think the issue is msal and msalService objects are getting initialised after success login redirect. Sorry if I am missing any details

Comment: Downvoted cause this is just a link post without any example and also link is dead

Comment: @gsubiran Sorry, I think the provided sample link have been updated in the recent times.

Comment: updated the answer as previous sample is currently not availble

Answer (score 0):

Get from the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` as per your configuration, if login success.

In some cases, after successful authentication, MSAL returns a different response than expected.

> The same issue can be reproducible as of today in the azure angular
> sample application downloaded from the Azure Portal > App Registrations > Select your App > Quick Start > SPA > Angular.